# Execute multiple commands for multiple devices using ssh2shell node.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, ssh, async-await, promise

In my project, I have an array of devices ip's, and an array of commands.
I need to open new ssh shell for each devcie, that executes all the commands in the same shell, so it won't open new connection for each command, and that's why I'm using [ssh2shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2shell) package.

The problem is that I need to wait all of them to end, and it needs to be async, so it won't wait for the answer from each ip before it's starts session with other device. After it get all of the responses it saves all that data in some array, that each cell in that array represents an ip response.

I know it's need to work with `async`, `await` or `Promise`, but I didn't succeed to manage it succesfully.

Main code:

```
function monitorDevices() {
    
    const DEVICES_IPS = [ "10.10.10.1", "20.20.20.1", "30.30.30.1" ];
    const COMMANDS    = [ "cat /var/log/messages", "cat /proc/stat", "df -h /var/log", "free -t -m" ];
    let data = [];
    DEVICES_IPS.forEach(device => {
       data.push(sshService.exec(device, COMMANDS));
    });

    console.log(data);

}
```

sshService code:

```
function exec(device, commands) {

    var host = {
     server: {     
      host:      device,
      userName:  process.env.USERNAME,
      password:  process.env.PASSWORD,
     },
     commands:      commands
    };
     
    var SSH2Shell = require ('ssh2shell'),
      SSH = new SSH2Shell(host),
      callback = function(sessionText){
        // if I console.log(sessionText) here, it gives my a good result.
        return sessionText;
      }

    SSH.connect(callback);

}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would Promise-wrap `SSH2Shell` and `SSH.connect` -

```js
const SSH2Shell = require ('ssh2shell')

function exec(device, commands) {
  const SSH = new SSH2Shell({ 
    server: {     
      host: device,
      userName: process.env.USERNAME,
      password: process.env.PASSWORD,
    },
    commands: commands
  })
  return new Promise(resolve => SSH.connect(resolve))
}
```

Now we write `monitorDevices` as an `async` function. Simply iterate thru `devices`, `await` each `sshService.exec` and `push` it to the `data` result -

```js
async function monitorDevices() {
  const devices =
    [ "10.10.10.1", "20.20.20.1", "30.30.30.1" ]

  const commands =
    [ "cat /var/log/messages", 
      "cat /proc/stat", 
      "df -h /var/log", 
      "free -t -m"
    ]

  const data = []
  for (const d of devices)
    data.push(await sshService.exec(d, commands))
  return data
}
```

To run the function, we write -

```js
monitorDevices().then(console.log, console.error)
```

My advice would be to make `devices` and `commands` parameters of the `monitorDevices` function -

```js
async function monitorDevices(devices, commands) {  // parameters
  const data = []
  for (const d of devices)
    data.push(await sshService.exec(d, commands))
  return data
}
```

Now it is reusable for various devices and commands -

```js
monitorDevices
  ( [ "10.10.10.1", ... ]              // devices
  , [ "cat /var/log/messages",  ... ]  // commands
  )
  .then(console.log, console.error)
```

Finally, we might wish to make our `exec` function a little more robust. We can add some error handling by wiring up to the host's `onError` property -

```js
function exec(device, commands) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
    new SSH2Shell({ 
      server: {     
        host: device,
        userName: process.env.USERNAME,
        password: process.env.PASSWORD,
      },
      commands: commands,
      callback: resolve,    // <- resolve callback
      onError: reject       // <- reject error
    })
}
```

Comment: Hi, first of all thank you. Second, the code didn't worked... It gives my only the result of the first device in the for loop... I did it exactly as you wroute except the last part because the SSH.connect wasn't there and didn't understand where to insert this.
Do you have idea why it works only on the first element of the array and how to fix it ?

Comment: Sorry it didn't work perfectly :( I haven't used the module so I based the code of the [documentation for the module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2shell). `SSH.connect` is an override of `host.callback` configuration. If it works for the first device, I can't imagine why it wouldn't work for the others. If I find the time later, I can get the module and try to find the bug. Let me know if you make any progress in the meantime.

Comment: Your code helped me with another module of SNMP service, so it's a good thing. About the SSH module, still no succes, but I am not giving up yet ;) Thanks for your help ! If you do find the time to try the module a bit, it would be awesome. thanks again